# SSRS using Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I go that url http://localhost/reports, there has been appear the "Authentication Required with username and password".
I didn't used the IIS. 
How can I do?
Please help me!.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to log in using the local administrator's account. Or the SQL Server administrator Windows login used during the SQLS/SSIS install.